# Recursive searching returns undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

I was just practicing some native Javascript and came across this problem. I'm building a comments widget and trying to implement a 'reply' button. For this I have to iterate through some n number of nested comments to find the correct one and push the reply to it's 'responses' attribute. This is my code so far:

```
 const recursiveSearch = (object, target) => {
    if(object.id === target) return object;

    let result;
    if(object.responses.length > 0) {
     object.responses.forEach(response => {
          if(response.id === target) {
              result = response;
              console.log('match found')
              console.log(response)
              return response
          } 
          
          else if(response.responses.length > 0) recursiveSearch(response, target) 
      })   
    };

    console.log('result Is')
    console.log(result)

    return result

}
```

The logs show the expected behavior just fine but when looking at the end return statement is undefined. Any way to get around this?

Comment: Your `else if` branch discards the result of the `recursiveSearch` call. `return` in `forEach` is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return from the recursive call and assign to the `result` variable again.

```js
const recursiveSearch = (object, target) => {
  if (object.id === target) return object;

  let result;
  if (object.responses.length > 0) {
    object.responses.forEach(response => {
      if (response.id === target) {
        result = response;
        console.log('match found')
        console.log(response)
        return response
      }

      else if (response.responses.length > 0) {
        result = recursiveSearch(response, target) // <--------------------
      }
    })
  };

  console.log('result Is')
  console.log(result)

  return result
}
```

You can also use a `find` instead of `forEach`. This is more efficient.

```js
const recursiveSearch = (object, target) => {
  if (object.id === target) return object;

  const result = object.responses.find(response => {
    if (response.id === target) {
      console.log('match found')
      console.log(response)
      return response
    }

    else if (response.responses.length > 0) {
      return recursiveSearch(response, target)
    }
  })

  console.log('result Is')
  console.log(result)

  return result
}
```

Comment: That still leaves `return response` inside a `forEach`, which does nothing, though the `result = response;` likely does what is intended.

Comment: This won't work when you use find as find return that item and not the function result

Comment: `find` should work as it will return the value of the recusrive call.

Comment: Find returns the value that currently is tested: `[1].find(() => 5)` will return 1 and not 5

Answer (score 2):

You can dramatically simplify your program using generators and reusable functions -

```js
function first(it) {
  for (const v of it)
    return v
}

function *search(t, id) {
  if (t.id == id) yield t
  for (const r of t.responses) yield *search(r, id)
}

const mydata = 
  { id: 1, responses: [
    { id: 2, responses: [] },
    { id: 3, responses: [] },
    { id: 4, responses: [
      { id: 5, responses: [] },
      { id: 6, responses: [] },
      { id: 7, responses: [] }
    ]},
    { id: 8, responses: [
      { id: 9, responses: [
        { id: 10, responses: [] }
      ]}
    ]}
  ]}

console.log(first(search(mydata, 8)))   // { id: 8, responses: [ ... ] }
console.log(first(search(mydata, 100))) // undefined
```

Even better is the choice to make `search` generic, accepting a `match` and `next` function. Now you can search input data of any type or shape with any fields. Ie, you're not limited to just `id` and `responses` -

```js
function first(it) {
  for (const v of it)
    return v
}

function *search(t, match, next) {
  if (Boolean(match(t))) yield t
  for (const r of next(t) ?? []) yield *search(r, match, next)
}

function mysearch(t, id) {
  return search(t, t => t.id == id, t => t.responses)
}

const mydata = 
  { id: 1, responses: [
    { id: 2, responses: [] },
    { id: 3, responses: [] },
    { id: 4, responses: [
      { id: 5, responses: [] },
      { id: 6, responses: [] },
      { id: 7, responses: [] }
    ]},
    { id: 8, responses: [
      { id: 9, responses: [
        { id: 10, responses: [] }
      ]}
    ]}
  ]}

console.log(first(mysearch(mydata, 8)))   // { id: 8, responses: [ ... ] }
console.log(first(mysearch(mydata, 100))) // undefined
```

Comment: This is what elegant code looks like!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return in your else if, but notice, you're inside a forEach, so maybe change it to regular for or use something else